# Разработка обновляемых приложении на WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Изучаю C# и WPF. Подскажите пожалуйста какие темы необходимо прочитать для реализации удаленного обновления приложения у конечного пользователя. Т.е. тот же VS при выходе новых обнов предлагает их установить, в принципе устанавливается только определенный пакет, а не все приложение переустанавливается))) Может есть разбор простого примера?

Comment: Мне кажется тут зависит от самого приложения. Если это утилита, то можно пойти по принципу скачивания архива с дальнейшей распаковкой его содержимого (с заменой). Если это большое приложение, то делается установщик, который после скачивается и устанавливается в автоматическом режиме. Способов обновления много, все зависит от вашей фантазии! Я к примеру, создал универсально консольное приложение, которое с моего сайта получает список файлов для моих проектов и их MD5, делаю проверку и изменившиеся файлы - заменяю. Получилась 1 утилита на все проекты, достаточно аргументом указать проект.

Comment: ClickOnce ?....

Comment: Ок, спасибо) думаю начать изучение с ClickOnce)

Comment: ClickOnce это хорошо, и даже больше, пользователь будет вправе откатить версию к предыдущему состоянию в случае сбоев.